# Failing to create Innerbean using Spring - BeanInstantiationException No default constructor found

Tags: java, spring

I started learning spring from Spring reference 3.0 and i wanted to try how to instantiate inner bean:

Here is my code:

```
package com.springexample;

public class ExampleBean {

 private String samplePropertyExampleBean;

 public void setSamplePropertyExampleBean(String samplePropertyExampleBean) {
  this.samplePropertyExampleBean = samplePropertyExampleBean;
 }

 public String getSamplePropertyExampleBean() {
  return samplePropertyExampleBean;
 }

 class InnerBean{

  private String sampleProperty;

  public void setSampleProperty(String sampleProperty) {
   this.sampleProperty = sampleProperty;
  }

  public String getSampleProperty() {
   return sampleProperty;
  }

 }


}
```

And my config file is:

When i am trying to retrieve the bean InnerBean i am getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'InnerBean' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.springexample.ExampleBean$InnerBean]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.springexample.ExampleBean$InnerBean.()

What could be the problem? I tried adding no-argument constructor in the InnerBean still i am getting error..

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's one caveat of Java - inner classes default constructor isn't a no-arg constructor. Their default constructor takes 1 parameter of type - the outer class.

So, use `<constructor-arg>` to pass a bean of type `ExampleBean`

Of course, use non-static inner classes only if this is necessary. If the class is only what you have shown, then make it `static`. Or move it to a new file. Then you won't have the above restriction. Preferring static inner classes is a good practice not only for spring beans, but in Java in general.

Comment: thanks Bozho. Great answer. It helped me instantiate an inner thread from spring.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include your Spring XML file, but I don't think it matters.

It doesn't work because `InnerBean` is an inner class. It can't be instantiated this way because there would be no enclosing instance of `ExampleBean`. (Try doing `new InnerBean()` in Java and you'll see the problem.)

If an `InnerBean` instance doesn't need to be encapsulated inside an `ExampleBean` instance, you could make `InnerBean` static. Then you would be able to instantiate it using Spring. Or you could make `InnerBean` a top-level (i.e. non-nested) class.

See [Nested Classes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in the Java Tutorials if you need to know more about inner classes.

Comment: Thanks Richard for the link..I think i need to brush up my basics..Thanks for ur time & link